# "Type not expected", using DataContractSerializer - but it's just a simple class, no funny stuff?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

*I'm refactoring my XML-serialization, and figured I'd try the DataContractSerializer.
Everything runs smoothly, until it needs to serialize this class:*

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace VDB_Sync.Model
{
[DataContract(Name="Konstant")]
public class Konstant : DataFelt
{
    [DataMember]
    private MySqlDbType mydataType;
    [DataMember]
    private object value;

    public Konstant(string navn, MySqlDbType dataType, object value)
        : base(navn, dataType, "*Konstant", false, false)
    {
        //this.navn = navn;
        this.mydataType = dataType;
        this.value = value;

        if (navn.Contains("*Løbenummer"))
        {
            navn = "*Konstant: " + Convert.ToString(value);
        }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

}
}
```

*It give's me this:*

> **Type 'VDB_Sync.Model.Konstant' with data contract name 'Konstant:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VDB_Sync.Model' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.**

*The help I've found so far points to collections and Types. I do have an enum (MySqlDbType) in my class - but get this: I even get the same error when i have no DataMembers declared at all :-x
So - what's going on here? What am I missing?

for reference, this is how i serialized it, VDB_SessionController being the root:*

```
    public void GemKonfig(VDB_SessionController session)
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
        {
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = "\t"
        };

        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(defaultFile, settings);
        DataContractSerializer ser =
            new DataContractSerializer(typeof(VDB_SessionController));

        ser.WriteObject(writer, session);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The exception that is being reported is for VDB_Sync.Model.Konstant. This means that somewhere further up the chain, this class is being pulled into another class and that class is the one being serialized.

The issue is that depending on how Konstant is embedded in this class (for example, if it is in a collection or a generic list), the DataContractSerializer may not be prepared for its appearance during deserialization.

To resolve this, you need to apply the known-type attribute to the class that contains Konstant. Based on your serialization code, I suspect that this is `VDB_SessionController`.

So, try decorating this class with the KnownType attribute:

```
[KnownType(typeof(VDB_Sync.Model.Konstant)]
public class VDB_SessionController
```

Comment: Awesome - it works!
Seems i need to do this with a lot of classes, thanks!

Comment: How would I go about adding this decoration if the class was generated by entity framework?

Comment: Thanks!. My issue was related to IReadOnlyCollection not being serializable. Got it to work by using an IList instead.

Answer (score 18):

Add this to WebApiConfig.cs

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;

json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Reference: http://www.datazx.cn/Forums/en-US/a5adf07b-e622-4a12-872d-40c753417645/action?threadDisplayName=web-api-error-the-objectcontent1-type-failed-to-serialize-the-response-body-for-content&forum=wcf

Comment: All this does is disables XML serialization, that's why this the exception goes away. However if you need XML serialization this answer won't help. Also you only need the last line: `config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);`

Everything above that line is irrelevant.

Answer (score 15):

You can also combine `[KnownType]` and reflection to make your code more resistant to future changes.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType("GetKnownPersonTypes")]
internal class Person
{
    private static IEnumerable<Type> _personTypes;

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes()
    {
        if (_personTypes == null)
            _personTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                    .GetTypes()
                                    .Where(t => typeof (Person).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                                    .ToList();
        return _personTypes;
    }
}
```

Now a `DataContractSerializer` / `DataContractJsonSerializer` / `XmlSerializer` configured to work with `Person`, will also work with *any* type derived from `Person` (as long as it's declared within the same assembly).

Answer (score 4):

use KnownTypeAttribute for resolving DataFelt class.
see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx

Answer (score 4):

It is like as @Leon suggested but with the fix from @Bryan, the 'KnownTypeAttribute' should be on the base class, so it should be like this:

```
[DataContract(Name="DataFelt")]
[KnownType(typeof(somenamespace.Konstant))]
public class DataFelt
```

and in the Subclass:

```
[DataContract(Name="Konstant")]
public class Konstant : DataFelt
```

Comment: You made my day!! I had these issue regarding a base class. But as the error message is not quite clear, I was very happy to read your solution here!!!

Answer (score 4):

The problem for me was that I was returning the Interface (IIndividual) from my WebAPI controller.  When I changed that return type to the Class (Individual) type, this error went away.

Not working:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/v1/Individual/Get/{id}")]
    public IIndividual Get([FromUri]int id)
    {
        return _individualService.Get(id);
    }
```

Working:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/v1/Individual/Get/{id}")]
    public Individual Get([FromUri]int id)
    {
        IIndividual individual = _individualService.Get(id);
        return individual as Individual;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
[DataContract(Name="Konstant")]
public class Konstant : DataFelt
```

to this:

```
[DataContract(Name="Konstant")]
[KnownTypes(typeof(somenamespace.DataFelt))]
public class Konstant : DataFelt
```

Comment: The KnownTypeAttribute needs to go on the base class.

Comment: What if you don't have access to the base type ?