# wcf Serialization issue with complex types

Tags: c#, wcf, fluent-nhibernate, datacontractserializer, complextype

possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794594/type-not-expected-using-datacontractserializer-but-its-just-a-simple-class)

I'm trying to serialize a set of objects using the standard `DataSerializer` which is used with `wcf`.

object structure:

```
[KnownType(typeof(PersonnelClassProperty))]
[KnownType(typeof(ResourceClassProperty))]
[KnownType(typeof(Person))]
[KnownType(typeof(PersonProperty))]
[KnownType(typeof(ResourceDefinitionProperty))]
[DataContract]
public class Person: ResourceDefinition
{
   [DataMember]
   public guid id {get; set;}

   [DataMember]
   public IList<PersonProperty> personProperties {get; set;}

   [DataMember]
   public IList<PersonnelClass> personnelClasses {get; set;}
}
```

PersonProperty : ResourceDefinitionProperty

- PersonnelClassProperty

PersonnelClass : ResourceClass

- Persons
- PersonnelClassProperty

PersonnelClassPoperty : ResourceClassProperty

The Above structure is mapped using `Nhibernate`. so the Base classes are `abstract classes` with base properties which we override into the main classes. we are using this so we can use a generic class for calling the CRUD functions in `Nhibernate`.

the first problem this poses is a circular reference, we fixed this. by resetting the lists of the objects we eliminated a circular reference problem.

we also loop through the properties and the associated class properties to get them, as they are being lazily loaded through `nHibernate`

this allowed me to generate some test data. we now have one `personnelclass` with a `personnelclassproperty`. these are being retrieved fine on its own. next we have a `person`. we added a reference to the `personnelclass`, and a `personnelclassproperty`. in the database we have an extra table that holds the reference for the link between the person and `personnelclass`, as this a `many-to-many relationShip`. the `personProperty` has a reference to a single `personnelClassproperty`, so a `FK` suffices here.

here, we run into the second problem, a serialization exception occurs:

> 'PersonnelClassPropertyProxy' with data contract name 'PersonnelClassPropertyProxy:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

so taken from the question mentioned in the first line i proceeded to add the `[DataContract]`, `[DataMember]` and `[KnownType(typeof(T))]` attributes to the classes mentioned above. where `T` is of course the correct type.

what happens is that we send person objects through wcf to a receiving party, which works fine if the is no link between the `personProperty` and the `personnelClassProperty`, but if we add a `personproperty` with a link to `PersonnelClassProperty`, we get the exception mentioned above.

all the examples and questions i see online work the same way

so concretely; what am i doing wrong? or what am i forgetting here?

i'll try to update the question with more code to illustrate the objects we use.

**edit:** I updated the structure of the `Person` object to show what i have done with the `KnownTypes`. note that this also holds the `personnelClassProperty` type, i have also did this for the `PersonProperty` object, because that is the actual class that holds the `PersonnelClassProperty` object, but a list of `personProperties` is used in `Person`. this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution. Because we are using `NHibernate`, we are `lazy loading` the `personnelClassProperty` into the `Personproperty` and eventually into the `Person`. this results into the `serialization exception`.

there are actually 2 solutions to solve the exception:

1: you can set the `Not.LazyLoad()` property instead of `LazyLoad()` at the mapping of the object to NHibernate

2: you can leave the `Lazyload()` property enabled and instead take an item from the object and do something with it before you try to serialize it. It is not enough to create a new variable like so:

```
PersonnelClassProperty classproperty = personProperty.PersonnelClassProperty;
```

you really have to do something with an internal object, like so:

```
PersonnelClassProperty classProperty = personProperty.PersonnelClassProperty;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(classproperty.Dbid);
```

we opted currently to use the `.Not.Lazyload()` option