# convert List<T> to IEnumerable<T> web api displays The type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I was trying to take a List  to output as IEnumerable and In the browser I get this error

> An error has occurred.
>   The 'ObjectContent1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.

**So for my URL for Web Api i'm using**

```
http://localhost/CoreWebApi/api/reference/GetAcademicLevels
```

**Web Api Controller method**

```
public IEnumerable<AcademicLevel> GetAcademicLevels()
{
   //  blah  blah blah ...

   var academicLevel = academicRepository.SelectAll().ToList();

   return academicLevel;
}
```

So NORMALLY this will be called from internally with RESTSHARP, which is like HTTPCLIENT  ,  so perhaps this message is not important?

Comment: A `List<T>` IS an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: The problem is probably not the fact that it's a `List<T>`. Take a look at this question instead. It may be because you try to serialize your entities. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098191/failed-to-serialize-the-response-in-web-api-with-json