# Failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api

I have a fairly simple Controller. My error is 'application/xml' unlike the Question redirected to me which is 'application/json'.

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
        private IProductService productservice = new ProductServices();

        public List<Employee> Get()
        {
            return productservice.GetProducts();
        }
    }
}
```

But I still get the following error.

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.

I have tried the following which did not work.

1. Added this in WebApiConfig.cs

   ```
   var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
   json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
   config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
   ```
2. Adding this in Global.asax.cs

   ```
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to serialize the response in Web API with Json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098191/failed-to-serialize-the-response-in-web-api-with-json)

Comment: none of the answers worked for me plus i am getting 'application/xml' error

Answer (score 0):

1. remove from WebApiConfig.cs

> var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
>   json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
>   Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
>   config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

then paste next code:

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

*and discard changes from Global.asax.cs*