# Exception: failed to serialize the response body in ASP.Net MVC 5 Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

So, I am learning how to create a Web Api in ASP.Net MVC 5. And I am stuck at one place and need guidance.

Steps Taken:

- Created an API Folder in Controller Folder and then a file "ResumesController.cs" inside it.

**ResumesController.cs**

```
public class ResumesController : ApiController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ResumesController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    //GET /api/resumes
    public IEnumerable<Resume> GetResumes()
    {
        var candidateId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var resumeList = _context
            .Resumes.Where(r => r.CandidateId == candidateId)
            .OrderByDescending(r => r.datetime);

        return resumeList;
    }

}
```

**Global.Asax**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

**Url exceuted:**

```
http://localhost:44395/api/resumes
```

Error Message:

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.

[image]

**Non Api Attempt: Works Fine**

```
  public ActionResult ResumeCenter()
        {
            var candidateId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var resumeList = _context
                .Resumes.Where(r => r.CandidateId == candidateId)
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.datetime);

            return View(resumeList);
        }
```

Folder and File Structure:

[image]

**Question 1:** I am learning via a tutorial and I don't understand how come I need to call `api/resumes`? Wy don't I need to call something like `/api/GetResumes`?

**Question 2:** Why am I not able to see the XML view of data returned?

P:S: Breakpoint is getting hit in the API Controller Action.

Attempt 1:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
            .Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Comment: WebApi has some routing smarts, eg URLs with a "Get" in the method name can be omitted, you can change this in the routing. As for your second question I found the duplicate - the solution is to return a Model (POCO) not an Entity Framework object, OR add some config to `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`, or try one of the handful of other good answers. Let me know if it is NOT an **exact** duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098191/failed-to-serialize-the-response-in-web-api-with-json

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Can you kindly put the link that I need to look into?

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Okey, I modified the Global.Asax and added some line of code and now it works. But I don't understand the tutorial I am watching does not add those lines still he is able to get the desired results? Wonder why?

Comment: Also, the answer I attempted has 71 upvotes w/o any explanation. Can you kindly explain me why it works for me now. (See my Added Attempt).

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Resume is my POCO. Its my Model. :-|

Comment: I changed to basic `return _context.Resumes.ToList();` But this also does not work.

Comment: Okey My Resume Model in turn uses some other Model. so, that might be the reason. :-|

Comment: Perhaps score some rep by posting your solution in the duplicate, or even a comment! It'll most likely help someone else... In the future!