# Returning the Web API response in JSON format

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, serialization, json-deserialization

I am trying sending a response from the API as a JSON. Currently we are calling other web service multiple times consuming it and send all the responses together as a JSON. The called web service returns response as a JSON. And below is what I am  doing

```
    List<Models.DTO.RootObject> i_response = new List<Models.TO.RootObject>();
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
    .....
   foreach (int req_id in reqIdLst)
   { 
     using (var client_request = new HttpClient())
      {
       string request_Uri = BaseURL_iLab;
       Uri uri_request = new Uri(request_Uri);
       client_request.BaseAddress = uri_request;
       client_request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
       client_request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
       client_request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

       var request_response = await client_request.GetAsync(uri_request);
       var responsefile = await request_response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var request_returnDataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.DTO.RootObject>(responsefile);

         i_response.Add(request_returnDataObj);
     }}
      return Ok(i_response);
  }}
```

But my above code throws error when debugging as

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content 
type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
```

I am not sure how to send as a JSON instead of a XML.

Comment: Besides not serializing to json, it seems like you have circular references in your model: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098191/failed-to-serialize-the-response-in-web-api-with-json . In web api, there is a content negotiation process to return the expected format depending on your client, you should not hard code your json format here.

Comment: You sure you are not attempting to deserializing an error? what is the returned http status code?

Comment: @PeterBons the http status code is 200. But throwing the above error

Comment: @KhanhTO But if I want to see the response in the browser how do I do that. Also the circular reference I am not sure what is wrong I am new to this

Comment: What is the content of  `responsefile`? did you inspect it?

Comment: @PeterBons responsefile is getting the response back from the web service as JSON.

Comment: Are you sure that your JSON is really matching RootObject ?

Answer (score 0):

Something we did where I work was to create a custom class that extends `ExceptionFilterAttribute`.  Call it something like `WebApiExceptionFilterAttribute`.  Create an override for `OnException` and set the `context.Response` appropriately based on the exception.  You can also set the `HttpStatusCode` if the exception indicates a specific result, such as NotFound, Forbidden, or BadRequest, instead of just InternalServerError.

Then, in `Global.asax`, in `Application_Start()`, add `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new WebApiExceptionFilterAttribute());`

Finally, when defining an `ApiController`, add a `[WebApiExceptionFilterAttribute]` annotation to the class definition.