# Failed to serialize the response in iis with Json

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, api, iis, xamarin.forms

when I try to get data from my API on IIS this error is shown

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."

this error is shown in my localhost also but when I wrote this code

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

the error is gone and the localhost is working fine right now,

> http://192.168.137.1:5020/api/prodects

no data back just error

> http://localhost:54740/api/prodects

data back and everything is fine

What am I missing?

Comment: What does this *question* have to do with SQL Server?

Comment: In which platform you run your code ? asp.net. xamarin, xamarin.forms or something else ?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098191/failed-to-serialize-the-response-in-web-api-with-json https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641386/failed-to-serialize-the-response-in-web-api

Comment: i run the code in asp.net api for xamarin application

Comment: the question with sql server that i have another error show with the error the previous error .. Cannot open database \"GdgShopDB\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'WORKGROUP\\DESKTOP-6GP9QOH$'."