# How do I return a list of objects from a restful WCF service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, wcf-rest

I am trying to return a list of objects from my restful WCF service. I am using Entity Framework. The problem is that when the WCF service runs and if I put a debugger on that then the debugger is visited twice and I get a `404` server not found error. Why is this happening.?

If I return a return a single `class(db table)` which is not having relation with other `class(DB table)` then it is returning the list but if I have to return a `class(DB table)` then I get a 404 error.

Interface :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetDataString/{value}",RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<Course> GetDataString(string value);
```

Implementation:

```
public List<Course> GetDataString(string value)
{
    int v = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    TestEntities1 t = new TestEntities1();
    List<Course> u = t.Courses.ToList();
    return u;
}
```

What can be the problem.? Here `Courses` is lined to `student table`.

When i write an ADO.NET code for fetching the same data, it works just fine.

Then after the debugger has executed twice I get a server not found error page and the URL changes from

```
http://localhost:5127
```

to

```
http://www.localhost.com:5127/Service1.svc/GetDataString/1/Service1.svc/GetDataString/1
```

also I enabled the trace and I am getting the following exception. I dont have any idea as to what this exception is. Please help.

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Message in stack trace for exception:

```
Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Course_4B21E9E950AEFDC2233FE771C1BFE0ABF63D591A6487C93CBD145965FB96EA11' with data contract name 'Course_4B21E9E950AEFDC2233FE771C1BFE0ABF63D591A6487C93CBD145965FB96EA11:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

Following is my Course class:

```
namespace JSONWebService
{
    [DataContract]
    public partial class course
    {
        public Course()
        {
            this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int C_Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string C_Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your web browser can't find a web server listening localhost:5127. Make sure it's running. (Hit F5 or Ctrl+F5) in VS.)

Comment: @abatishchev : No, when i write an ADo.net code for fetching the same data, it works just fine.

Comment: The way how you fetch data isn't related to the web server availability. Double check it's running. For example, put a breakpoint and make sure it's being hit.

Comment: Also you may get an exception that kills the web server process, it's quite possible.

Comment: Anyway, debug your application. Find the line causing an exception, if any.

Comment: @abatishchev : I debugged it. Debugger is getting visited twice which should visit only once. That is also something strange

Comment: @abatishchev : Not helping , did it many times.

Comment: What is the stack trace when the breakpoint is being hit, is it equal both times or different?

Comment: @abatishchev : I am getting exception as System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Comment: @user2998990 can you post full stack trace for the exception

Comment: Please look at this question which might answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794594/type-not-expected-using-datacontractserializer-but-its-just-a-simple-class

Comment: @CoderofCode : I will try..  but I am a new bird with WCF. If you can please explain me the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your service doesn't know how to serialize `course` class. Did you add `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes to it ? Can you post how it looks ?

Comment: I had added it to course class. Do i need to add it to course class or student class.?

Comment: @user2998990 You need to Add `[DataContact]` and `[DataMember]` to student class also or else need to add the `[KnownType(typeof(student)]` attribute

Comment: @CoderofCode : [KnownType(typeof(student)] on student class or course.?

Comment: @CoderofCode,tchrikch : I have not written the classes. The classes are auto generated when I added the entity datamodel(edmx). Please help. Nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you cannot transfer an object as its base type between a WCF server and client. The DataContractSerializer will throw an exception when it attempts to serialize the base class, You can find good article regarding your problem in [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1003/wcf-tutorial-serializing-and-transmitting-base-types)

Comment: Ado.net doent have a problem as it is not interacting with classes..? Rite..?? Coz using ado.net gives me proper results.

Comment: WCF uses serialization to transfer data from server to client. but Ado.net doesn't. the WCF and ADo.net are totally different concepts. Ado.net uses to get data from DB and WCF uses to transfer data from one end to another.

Comment: I know.. what i am saying is.. in the WCF service itself instead of using EF and LINQ , I am using ado.net code(STored Procedures) for fetching data and storing data returned by SP in dataset and converting it to list and then returning. In this case everythin works fine