# Serialization issue in wcf rest service

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-rest

With refernce to my previous question

[Return a list of objects from a restful WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351267/return-a-list-of-objects-from-a-restful-wcf-service?noredirect=1#comment43159365_27351267)

I enabled the `trace` and I am geting the following exception. I dont have any idea as to what this exception is. Please help.

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Message:

```
Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.course_4B21E9E950AEFDC2233FE771C1BFE0ABF63D591A6487C93CBD145965FB96EA11' with data contract name 'course_4B21E9E950AEFDC2233FE771C1BFE0ABF63D591A6487C93CBD145965FB96EA11:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

Comment: Can you update the previous question with this info so it will be more help full to you as the people who commented on that question can give you better answers.

Comment: What is your full exception can you post stacktrace