# AddXmlDataContractSerializer Fails while serializing child resources

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters to Serialize the data in XML as an output stream but getting the following issue again and again though it works fine with JSON

Here are my setup classes:

```
class ADto 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<BDto> BDtos { get; set; } = null;
}

class BDto 
{ 
  public string Description{ get; set; }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController] 
public class AController : ControllerBase 
{
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetAs()
   { 
     // some logic

   }
}
```

> Error "Message": "An unexpected fault happened. Try again
> later.\nError:Type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[....Models.Dtos.BDto, ....API,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with data
> contract name
> 'ArrayOfBDto:[http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/....API.Models.Dtos'](http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/....API.Models.Dtos%27)
> is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of
> known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute
> or by adding them to the list of known types passed to
> DataContractSerializer."

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`KnownTypeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) for resolving the issue.

For more details, you can refer [the sample codes and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8795410/7687666).

> Note:
>
> In your code, you can use the word KnownType instead of the longer KnownTypeAttribute.